# How to name a function that creates fixpoint results on its input?

Tags: api, naming-conventions, decorator, naming, api-design

I have a function that decorates a string. If the decorated string is again fed to the function, it is guaranteed not to change. How is the standard naming convention for such a function? I'll probably create a namespace because I need to have a few of those functions.

I've come up with:

```
repetition_safe.decorate(me);
fixpoint_gen.decorate(me);
one_time_effect.decorate(me);
```

but I don't really like any of these.

How would you name the namespace or function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
StringDecorator.MakeImmutable(input);
```

I think "MakeImmutable" is better than "Decorate" as the later is ambiguous i.e. a user reading the code won't know what "decorate" does, whereas "makeImmutable" will inform the user that this function will make the input string immutable/non-changable.